# In xamarin forms, how can I focus a control when its label is tapped?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In my page, I display a list of questions, each with a template similar to this:

```xml
<Grid Margin="5,5,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Text="{Binding Header}" FontSize="Medium" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <Entry Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TextValue}" />
</Grid>
```

How can I also focus the entry when the label is tapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a [TappedGestureRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap#using-xaml)

```
<Label Text="{Binding Header}" FontSize="Medium" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
  <Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped" />
  </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
<Entry x:Name="myEntry" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TextValue}" />
```

then in your code behind

```
void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    myEntry.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Great. Will that work in a list though? I mean giving a name to a control in a template that is used to build a list, wouldn't make the control accessible in the code? Ahh, but I can reach my ViewModel through the sender's bindingcontext, and then I'll have the control through that. Awesome. Let me try.

Comment: why don't just use the LIstView's built in ItemTapped instead?

Comment: I moved away from ListViews, I'm using StackLayout now, and BindableLayout.ItemsSource.